# weighted directed Walk in a graph

Tags: graph-theory

I have a problem in graph theory and search the name and the complexity of the following problem :

Let $G = (V,A)$ be a directed graph, $p : A \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ be a weight on the arcs of $G$ and $k_1, k_2\in \mathbb{N}$.

Is there a walk $w$ of $G$ of length $k_1$ ($w = (v_{i_1} \ldots v_{i_{k_1}})$) such that $\sum_{j = 1}^{n-1}p((v_{i_j},v_{i_{j+1}})) \leq k_2$ ?

Can you help to find the name and the complexity of this problem ?
Anybody has ever read something on this?

Answer (score 1):

This problem is PP-hard under Turing reductions when your weights are encoded in binary. The lower bound follows by a reduction from the $K$-th largest subset problem. Given a set $S\subseteq \{ s_1,\ldots,s_n \}\subseteq \mathbb{N}$ and $B, K\in \mathbb{N}$, this problem asks whether
\begin{align*}
\# \{ S'\subseteq S : \sum_{s\in S'} s \le B \} \ge K.
\end{align*}
It has recently been [shown](http://arxiv.org/abs/1501.06729) that this problem is PP-complete under polynomial-time Turing reductions. It's easily seen how to encode this problem into yours (and see Proposition 4 in [here](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-540-31982-5_9) in case you need some inspiration).

If $k_1$ is given in unary then your problem is PP-complete. If $k_1$ is given in binary then your problem is in PEXP, I cannot say if it is PEXP-complete.

In general, you often see this kind of problems in the setting of quantitative verification of (stochastic) systems.